# Output variable to webform ListItem in aspx file

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm trying to output a few variables for the text and value for `ListItem` elements, in an `aspx` file.

This is what I have (which does not work). The problem has to do with outputting the variables to the `ListItem`, though I do not know the specific error (I don't have the web.config set up to show errors and am unable to update that at the moment).

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" name="ExpYear" id="ExpYear">
    <%
    int expirationYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        string expirationYearShort = expirationYear.ToString().Substring(2);
        %>
        <asp:ListItem value='<%= expirationYearShort %>'><%= expirationYear %></asp:ListItem>
        <%
        expirationYear++;
    }
    %>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I understand this isn't a good approach, but is there a way to do accomplish this?

Comment: Are you able to create a test project containing this code, and seeing if you can replicate itself in an environment that does allow you to alter the web.config? I'm pretty sure that's all that everyone else would be doing.

Comment: God kill a little kity when someone mix presentation code and logic like you do...

Comment: I understand that, as I stated in the question. This is legacy code and this is how things were done. Rather than hard code the expiration years, I'd like to just show the current + next 3 years for the drop down choices.

Comment: You can not include code blocks inside of the DropDownList control like that. It throws a parse error: "Code blocks are not supported in this context."

Comment: @iacii So, there's no way to do this, then?

Comment: Not in your presentation layer like that. You could just use an HTML `<select>` tag with your embedded code if that meets your needs.

Comment: @iacii Thanks. I chose to just hard-code the values as it was previously done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the neatest code, as I've deliberately written it to ensure the core is as close as your original as possible to allow comparisons. However, it does seem to meet your requirements:

```
<script runat="server">

  protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {

    int expirationYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    ExpYear.Items.Clear();
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
      string expirationYearShort = expirationYear.ToString().Substring( 2 );
      ExpYear.Items.Add( new ListItem( expirationYearShort, expirationYear.ToString() ) );
      expirationYear++;
    }
  }

</script>

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ExpYear" />
```

Comment: Actually, `expirationYearShort` should be in my question, I made a mistake. It should be just the last two digits of the year (ex: 13).

Comment: I've altered the code to use expirationYearShort as the text, by adding a new ListItem instead of just `expirationYear.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a way to accomplish this. I ended up deciding to just hard-code the values I need.

If anyone has a better solution, please share.

Comment: I'm almost tempted to downvote you for giving an incorrect answer to your own question. ;)